# How to get list of selected files when using GetOpenFileName() with multiselect flag?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

I have tried googling, but people seem to have the same problem: we can't get a list of the selected files.

This is a simple piece of working code that is similar to what I use:

```
OPENFILENAME ofn = { sizeof ofn };
wchar_t file[1024];
file[0] = '\0';
ofn.lpstrFile = file;
ofn.nMaxFile = 1024;
ofn.Flags = OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT | OFN_EXPLORER;
GetOpenFileName(&ofn);
```

How do I actually get the filenames I selected? Currently I can only get it to work without OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT flag, so it returns the one selected filename into `ofn.lpstrFile`. I tried to print out all the string variables inside that struct, but found nothing. It only shows the main folder of the selected files.

Comment: its in the docs on the structure [**`OPENFILENAME`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646839(v=vs.85).aspx). Multiple selections are separated by null chars in a contiguous buffer, with the *last* selection terminated by **two** null chars. The usual method to gather them is to walk the string in a `while (*s){ ... s = s+lstrlen(s)+1; }`, where `s` is initially the starting address of said buffer.

Comment: It's way easier to use `IFileDialog`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the `ofn.lpstrFile` contains all the filenames, separated with a NULL and ending with another NULL (effectively ending with an empty string).

> **If the OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT flag is set and the user selects multiple files, the buffer contains the current directory followed by the file names of the selected files. For Explorer-style dialog boxes, the directory and file name strings are NULL separated, with an extra NULL character after the last file name.** For old-style dialog boxes, the strings are space separated and the function uses short file names for file names with spaces. You can use the FindFirstFile function to convert between long and short file names. **If the user selects only one file, the lpstrFile string does not have a separator between the path and file name.**

*From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646839(v=vs.85).aspx).*

A possible implementation to parse the contents could be;

```
wchar_t* str = ofn.lpstrFile;
std::wstring directory = str;
str += ( directory.length() + 1 );
while ( *str ) {
  std::wstring filename = str;
  str += ( filename.length() + 1 );
  // use the filename, e.g. add it to a vector
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the first item in the buffer is the directory: `wchar_t* str = ofn.lpstrFile; std::wstring dir = str; str += (dir.length()+1); while (*str) { ... }`

Comment: Thanks @Remy, I forgot that, just focused on the  NULL parsing

Comment: Actually, to complicate it, if only one file is selected, the sole item in the buffer is both path + filename, so you have to account for that as well. If one item is present, use as-is. If multiple items are present, the first is directory and the rest are filenames. The struct does not tell you which case is which, you have to parse the buffer to discover it.

Comment: @Remy, that does complicate it. I guess a check with nFileOffset could be used here, I'm not sure how the OP would integrate this into their own code.

Comment: `nFileOffset` is meaningful in both single-file and multi-file scenarios. It points to the first filename, so that does make things a little easier. In both scenarios, everything before `nFileOffset` is a directory, which may or may not be null terminated, and everything from `nFileOffset` onward is 1 or more filenames.

Comment: I decided to use this snippet without wchar_t (got some errors from it not able to cast etc). and i just push them all into vector<string> and later loop it through to generate the full paths, depending on how many items the vector<string> has; if 1, then use it as filename, if more than 1, then use first element as the folder for rest of the elements.

Comment: Thats fine, the wchar_t vs char depends on how TCHAR is defined. If UNICODE is doing, then wide, else narrow.

Answer (score 1):

Checking nFileExtension may NOT be reliable because it can also be 0 if the user entered no file extension (but just the dot, like "file.").
I think to distinguish between single and multi file selection one has to check if there is a null character (terminator) at position nFileOffset - 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
wchar_t file[1025] = {0}; // room for an extra null terminator, just in case
...
ofn.nMaxFile = 1024;
...
wchar_t* ptr = ofn.lpstrFile;
ptr[ofn.nFileOffset-1] = 0;
std::wcout << L"Directory: " << ptr << std::endl;
ptr += ofn.nFileOffset;
while (*ptr)
{
    std::wcout << L"File: " << ptr << std::endl;
    ptr += (lstrlenW(ptr)+1);
}
```

Comment: Surely `ofn.nMaxFile` should be 1025, not that it really matters of course, but the docs say this is the size of the buffer, in characters.

Comment: I intentionally made the buffer larger than `nMaxFile` so there is always a null terminator regardless of how `GetOpenFileName()` fills the buffer. It is a safety catch for the loop that looks for null terminators. I don't care if `GetOpenFileName()` outputs its own null terminator or not.  I prefer to err on the side of caution when using sized buffers.  An extra slot in the buffer doesn't hurt.

Comment: `GetOpenFileName` will return `FALSE` if the buffer is not large enough. And large enough includes being able to write all the necessary null terminators.

Comment: I don't care. I prefer to have my own safety catch on top of whatever the API provides. If you don't like it, you don't have to use it. But don't criticize the way I choose to write code.

Comment: I'll criticise whatever I like thank you very much. It's fine for you to code that way. I'm just saying that it is unnecessarily pessimistic.

Comment: I would add the nullbyte just in case... better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you select a single file when using OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT, the nFileExtension field contains the offset to the extension. If you select multiple files, the nFileExtension field contains 0.

This way you can determine if a single file was selected, and just read/copy the buffer pointed to by the lpstrFile field (which will be a single null terminated string containing the full path and filename including extension)

or if multiple files where selected, then you parse the buffer pointed to by the lpstrFile field, using nFileOffset to read/copy the folder first (using lstrcpyn for example and specifying length to read as the nFileOffset value) and then read/copy from nFileOffset to next null which is file1 string, add the file string length +1 to get next position to read/copy next file string etc till you reach a file string that starts with null - which is the double null for end of all files (as the last string before this is null terminated)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more complete version of the answers by Niall and Remy.

```
vector<string> &filePaths;

if ( GetOpenFileName( &ofn ) == TRUE )
{
    wchar_t *p = ofn.lpstrFile;
    wstring path = p;
    p += path.size() + 1;
    if ( *p == 0 )
    {
        // there is only one string, being the full path to the file
        filePaths.push_back( ConvertWideCharToUtf8( path.c_str() ) );
    }
    else
    {
        // multiple files follow the directory
        for ( ; *p != 0 ; )
        {
            wstring fileName = p;
            filePaths.push_back( ConvertWideCharToUtf8( ( path + L"\\" + fileName ).c_str() ) );
            p += fileName.size() + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Where we also have the function:

```
string ConvertWideCharToUtf8( const wchar_t *wideText )
{
    int len = WideCharToMultiByte( CP_UTF8, 0, wideText, -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL );
    char *buffer = (char *)malloc( len );
    WideCharToMultiByte( CP_UTF8, 0, wideText, -1, buffer, len, NULL, NULL );
    string s = buffer;
    free( buffer );

    return s;
}
```